# Simple datastore entity with 2 fields that are also unique

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

All I am trying to produce is an entity that holds a unique username, and a unique device ID, and the ability to return an error if either of these conditions are not met on submission.

The only way I can see is to perform a query within a transaction, then filter the results. This however requires an ancestor (which seems unnecessary for a single simple entity).

What is the best method to go about doing this?

Comment: Use get_or_insert. It can use a parent, parent entity key, if any.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert

Comment: How can you programatically tell whether the returned entity is a new or existing one though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that does what you want.

I put 2 entities to show you also how to make relationships

```
class Person(ndb.Expando):

    registration_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def info(self):
        info = PersonInfo.query(ancestor=self.key).get()
        return info

class PersonInfo(ndb.Expando):

    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    nick_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    edit_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

Later in the controller for register:

```
class RegisterPersonHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user() #Stub here 
        if not user:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri), abort=True)
            return
        person = Person.get_or_insert(user.user_id())
        if not self._register(person, user):
            # more logging is needed
            logging.warning('Warning registration failed')
            return


    @ndb.transactional()
    def _register(self, person, user):
        ''' Registration process happens here
        '''
        # check if the person has info and if not create it
        info = PersonInfo.query(ancestor=person.key).get()
        if not info:
            info = PersonInfo(id=user.user_id(), parent=person.key)
            info.nick_name = user.nickname()
            info.email = user.email()
            info.put()
        return True
```

To answer also the comment question:

> How can you programatically tell whether the returned entity is a new
>   or existing one though?

Try checking against a property that is default. Eg `creation_date` etc. 
Though you can also check on something you need or on another entity's existence like I do because I expect the data to be consistent, and if not then create the bond.

Comment: Thanks, that's sorted it.